# StoreKit doesn't like product identifiers loaded from a pList

Tags: ios, swift, plist, storekit

I have been trying to get StoreKit to work over the last 2 days. 
I found many possible faults and remedies via stack overflow. I haven't seen this particular problem mentioned anywhere.

The first code snippet shows what works in my project. It uses a hardcoded product ID string and returns a SKProduct via the appropriate delegate function. It works on both a device and the simulator (iOS 8.4).

```
private var request : SKProductsRequest?
func fetchProducts()
{       
    self.request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(["TestProductA","Test Product A"]))
    self.request?.delegate = self
    self.request?.start()
}
```

But if I use the same product ID loaded from a plist, then it doesn't work anymore. I immediately get the typically vague error "cannot connect to store". Why this is not working escapes me for the moment.

```
func fetchProducts()
{
    if let productList = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Products", withExtension: "plist"),
        let productIdentifiers = NSArray(contentsOfURL: productList) as? [String]
    {
        self.request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(arrayLiteral: productIdentifiers))
        self.request?.delegate = self
        self.request?.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly question, but have you manually inspected the results of loading from the plist via the debugger before and after you turn them into a set? Anything at all look different between the two?

Comment: It's not a silly question. No, I don't see anything different. The product ID is copy/paste. But even an invalid product ID should work. In that case StoreKit returns it as an invalid product ID. I know because I am using 1 valid and 1 invalid product ID for testing (Apple recommends doing this).

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the Set?

Comment: It might have something to do with the set you're creating; that's part of my inspection question - turn your plist results into a set (for inspection) _then_ set the productRequest. Even better, log this stuff during a run and add the output to the question. Maybe that will expose something that seems obvious or otherwise isn't likely to be randomly stumbled upon.

Comment: The output from the set is the same (same strings). By specifically setting the type of the Set members, it now works fine. See the answer I posted.

Comment: Glad you have it resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to change how the set is created.

```
self.request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set<String>(productIdentifiers))
```